# Error appearing when opening a layout in the project

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I wish this time my question is clear. I try to open one layout but I get an error like that appearing in the picture. If I click ok, it opens but in the content tab not appears its content while I still see in any opened tabs the same content. This projects worked fine till I made latest java update could be it the problem? 
[image: project error shot]

[image: log shot]

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectResources.getMatchingFile(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/android/resources/ResourceType;Lcom/android/ide/common/resources/configuration/FolderConfiguration;)Lcom/android/ide/common/resources/ResourceFile;
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationMatcher.isCurrentFileBestMatchFor(ConfigurationMatcher.java:147)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationMatcher.findAndSetCompatibleConfig(ConfigurationMatcher.java:324)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationChooser.onXmlModelLoaded(ConfigurationChooser.java:782)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.onTargetChange(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1186)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.onDescriptorsChanged(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:916)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegateInitUiRootNode(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:835)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegateXmlModelChanged(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:393)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.xmlModelChanged(CommonXmlEditor.java:329)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor$XmlModelStateListener.modelChanged(AndroidXmlEditor.java:1653)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.createTextEditor(AndroidXmlEditor.java:835)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.createAndroidPages(AndroidXmlEditor.java:320)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.addPages(AndroidXmlEditor.java:310)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.addPages(CommonXmlEditor.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2945)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2850)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2842)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2789)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2773)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2764)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your installation is corrupted. One of the .jars the Eclipse plugin depends on is not up to date, so there's an argument mismatch when it is trying to call into it. Try reinstalling the ADT plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how I haven't used eclipse since latest updates of SDK and ADT 21 in the while also Java required and update I supposed was something connected with java version or path. I followed your suggestion to uninstall and reinstall the ADT so now it works again.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem while opening main.xml file in eclipse. I solved it by Updating ADT plugin in eclipse -

**-> Go to Help -> Eclipse Market Place -> Type adt in filter search -> Look for Android Development Tools For Eclipse -> Update.**

Problem SOLVED.!!
Cheers..